# Ordering binary matrices for reflection/rotation

Tags: matrices, algorithms, symmetry, sorting

I have a collection of $n\times n$ binary matrices and I would like to reduce it for symmetry ($D_4$ -- reflections and rotations). The naive method of testing each pair is very slow because the collection is large. Is there some ordering I can use so that duplicates will be nearby (or even a canonicalization)? If it's easy enough to implement this could reduce the number of comparisons from $\sim n^2/2$ to $\sim n\log_2n$ which would be a big improvement.

Comment: Is the problem about finding a fast way of recognizing whether two matrices $A$ and $B$ are in the same orbit of $D_4$, or is it about speeding up the checking whether a "new" matrix $B$ is in the same orbit as any of the "earlier matrices" in the list $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_N$ by keeping that list sorted (according to a sought after quickly computable total order) so that you can test whether $B$ is $D_4$-equivalent to any of the matrices in the list by comparing it with at most $\log_2N$ of the matrices $A_i$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: The latter is closer to my application. I have a list of matrices (say, 50,000) and I want to count the number up to rotation and reflection.